# Powershell RegEx Pattern Not Returning Expected Results

Tags: regex, powershell

This is my current PowerShell script:

```
Select-String -Path C:\mylogfiles*.log -AllMatches -Pattern "(?<= I really care what is to come: )'.*?'" | ForEach-Object { foreach ($phrase in $_.Matches.Value) { [pscustomobject] @{ Phrase = $phrase.Trim("'") } } } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 result.csv
```

Unfortunately that is producing a result.csv file with just garbage text in column A row 1.  Prior to this I had the following which was working:

```
Select-String -Path C:\mylogfiles\*.log -AllMatches -Pattern "'.*?'" | ForEach-Object {
foreach ($phrase in $_.Matches.Value) {
  [pscustomobject] @{ Phrase = $phrase.Trim("'") }
} } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 result.csv
```

After the working script, worked, I realized I had some additional information between single quotes that I do not need in my results.  Therefore, I had to find everything in single quotes that comes after the words:  I really care what is to come:

As requested, here is the contents of my log file.  From my test.log file the following line is in there:

```
Failed to find the computername:  'ComputerA.domain.com' More text which is confidential so I can't post it.
```

Running the script produces a result.csv file that is garbage text as previously indicated.

Actual script that fails:

```
Select-String -Path C:\test.log -AllMatches -Pattern "(?<= Failed to find the computername: )'.*?'" | ForEach-Object { foreach ($phrase in $_.Matches.Value) { [pscustomobject] @{ Phrase = $phrase.Trim("'") } } } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 result.csv
```

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Sorry, but without actual file contents and more specific requirements this question is hard to answer.

Comment: Please add sample text from your log files that reproduces the problem and show the actual vs. the expected result.

Comment: I edited the original question so hopefully that is seen now?  I was not sure the proper etiquette if I should edit the question or comment.

Comment: @Lery: Editing the question directly was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest matching optional whitespace after `:` and use `\s` to match the whitespaces:

```
Select-String -Path C:\test.log -AllMatches
  -Pattern "(?<=\bFailed\s+to\s+find\s+the\s+computername:\s*)'.*?'" | 
    ForEach-Object { 
      foreach ($phrase in $_.Matches.Value) { 
        [pscustomobject] @{ 
          Phrase = $phrase.Trim("'") 
        }
      }
    } | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 result.csv
```

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Failed                   'Failed'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    to                       'to'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    find                     'find'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    the                      'the'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    computername:            'computername:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, all whitespace in a regex ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)) is significant:

- Therefore, a look-behind assertion such as `(?<= Failed to find the computername: )` only matches input strings where `Failed` is preceded by a space.
- Similarly, the trailing space is significant, and it seems that *two* spaces are present in your actual input; a simple and flexible way to handle this is to add duplication symbol `+` after the space, which means that one *or more* spaces match; this is what is used in the solutions below, which focus on variant solutions to handle the problem with the leading case.

Note:

- If the whitespace in your input isn't just made up of *spaces*, as your sample input suggests, but may contain *tab* characters, for instance, use `\s` to match it, as shown in [Ryszard Czech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68041962/45375).

It looks like your input strings may not have a leading space before the word `Failed`, so in the simplest case you can just remove the leading whitespace from the look-behind assertion:

```
"(?<=Failed to find the computername: +)'.*?'"
```

If you want to ensure that the string only matches at the *start* of an input line:

```
"(?<=^Failed to find the computername: +)'.*?'"
```

If matching in the interior of a line is also desired but you want to make sure that `Failed` is its own word (rather than being part of a larger, hypothetical word such as `FooFailed`), use a word-boundary assertion:

```
"(?<=\bFailed to find the computername:  +)'.*?'"
```

---

Here's the command with some sample input lines, and without the `Export-Csv` part; note that matching is case-insensitive by default, as PowerShell generally is (add `-CaseSensitive` to the `Select-String` call, if needed):

```sh
"Failed to find the computername:  'ComputerA.domain.com' More text which is confidential so I can't post it.",
"Unrelated 'stuff'",
"I failed to find the computername:  'ComputerB.domain.com' ..." |
  Select-String  -Pattern "(?<=\bFailed to find the computername:  +)'.*?'" |
    Select-Object -Property @{ Name='Phrase'; Expression = { $_.Matches.Value.Trim("'") } }
```

The above outputs the following as expected:

```
Phrase
------
ComputerA.domain.com
ComputerB.domain.com
```

Comment: I tried it as you suggested and still get the same result.  If you create the same file, with the exact text I pasted in, yours works?

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working for me.  I took your example, and it works.  I just use it against the log file and nothing.  The log file has the exact contents as you listed in your example and as I have listed.  Nothing is different in there.

Comment: @Lery: Perhaps Ryszard Czech's answer solves your problem: my assumption, based on your sample input, was that the input only contains actual _space_ characters.

Comment: Yes it did!  I wanted to also thank you for your time and effort on this one.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution, @Lery; my pleasure.